# Storing and retrieving Active Directory objectGUID in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I am close to making this work. I need to identify a user on our intranet. I need to store that user's `objectGUID` in a SQL Server database table, and be able to retrieve that record again. I have several different applications, PHP, ASP Classic and ASP.Net. I thought it might be easiest to perform the AD lookup in SQL Server.

I am able to connect to AD by using the steps in this tutorial http://sql.dzone.com/news/querying-active-directory-thro

I can retrieve the `objectGUID` and anything else I need, but I am not sure how to store the `objectGUID` in the database or how to query the database using the `objectGUID`.

I think it is the data type (128 length byte array?) and needs to be converted but I am not sure how to do it.

Selecting a record from active directory and inserting into a table shows the data type  inserted objectGUID as varbinary(256)

```
select  *
into temp_table
from  openquery(adsi, '
select  givenName,
                sn,
                sAMAccountName,
                objectGUID              
from    ''LDAP://dc=somedomain,dc=com''
where   sAMAccountName = ''some_user''
')
```

Just to test, I tried querying AD with objectGUID retrieved from the temp_table above.

```
declare @qry varchar(8000)
declare @var varbinary(256)
set @var = (SELECT objectGUID from temp_table)
set @qry = 'select *
from openquery(ADSI, ''
    select
    givenName, 
    sn, 
    sAMAccountName
    from ''''LDAP://DC=somedomain,DC=com'''' 
    where objectGUID = ''''+@var+''''   
    ORDER BY displayName
'')'

exec(@qry)
```

Returns no rows...

Initially I thought this was the right syntax with the quotes

```
where objectGUID = '+@var+'
```

but returned an error: Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals add, type equals varchar

So maybe I am close with wrong syntax, or still a data type problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to use objectGUID in the where clause, but I did find that I could bind directly to the objectGUID which gives me the same end result.

```
DECLARE @qry varchar(8000) 
DECLARE @ObjectGUID uniqueIdentifier

SET @ObjectGUID = (SELECT objectGUID FROM temp_table)

SET @qry = 'select *
FROM openquery(ADSI, ''
    SELECT  givenName,
                sn,
                sAMAccountName,
                objectGUID              
from    ''''LDAP://<GUID=' + CAST(@ObjectGUID as CHAR(36)) + '>''''
'')'

EXEC(@qry)
```

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve data from AD in single query, when You ask for specific object GUID or multiple GUIDs, there is a way to use `where` clause instead of `from LDAP://<GUID=your guid>` expression (which is very convenient in the case of query for single GUID).

The GUID of Active Directory object in where clause of Your query must have a form of string where GUID's every byte expressed in hexadecimal notation is preceded by backslash sign:

```
\1B\C1\93\F8\25\32\72\4E\8B\48\48\62\BB\44\49\7A
```

For example, You have the GUID: `F893C11B-3225-4E72-8B48-4862BB44497A`. First, You have to convert it to `binary(16)` type (byte array of length 16) and then convert to hexadecimal string and finally insert backslashes like in example above:

```
declare @g uniqueidentifier = 'F893C11B-3225-4E72-8B48-4862BB44497A';
declare @gs nvarchar(max);

set @gs = CONVERT(nvarchar(max), CONVERT(binary(16), @g), 2);

declare @c int = 16;
while @c > 0
begin
set @c = @c - 1;
set @gs = STUFF(@gs, (2 * @c) + 1, 0, '\');
end;

declare @q nvarchar(max) = 
'select * from openquery(AD, 
'' select cn from ''''LDAP://DC=domain,DC=com'''' 
where objectGUID = ''''' + @gs + '''''  
'')';

exec(@q);
```

Above code creates a following query:

```
select * from openquery(AD, 'select cn from ''LDAP://DC=domain,DC=com'' where objectGUID = ''\1B\C1\93\F8\25\32\72\4E\8B\48\48\62\BB\44\49\7A'' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `CAST` or `CONVERT` in TSQL? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx has a couple examples.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean by "how to query the database using the objectGUID", but if you want to know the exact datatype, there are two ways:

1. If you are using at least SQL Server 2012, then you can try [sp_describe_first_result_set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx). It has several restrictions so does not work in all situations.
2. You can dump the results to a temp table and then examine its structure:

   ```
   SELECT fields
   INTO #tmp
   FROM openquery(...);

   EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_help '#tmp';
   ```

Use whatever datatype is returned (probably `BINARY(128)` or `VARBINARY(128)`) when creating columns to store the values or when declaring local variables.

**EDIT:**
So we now know that `objectGUID` is a VARBINARY(256).  In order to use that properly in your query, remove three sets of single-quotes from the escaped string within an already escaped string. Also, we need to convert the VARBINARY to a VARCHAR so that it can be concatenated into the Dynamic SQL string. When using the `CONVERT` function be sure to use the "style" number of `1` which translates the hex digits to a string of hex digits (i.e. "0x12D5"); if you don't specify a "style" the default action is to translate to the characters denoted by those hex digits (i.e. "Hello!").

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(8000),
        @ObjectGUID VARBINARY(256);

SELECT @ObjectGUID = objectGUID
FROM   temp_table;

SET @Query = 'SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, ''
    SELECT
    givenName, 
    sn, 
    sAMAccountName
    FROM ''''LDAP://DC=somedomain,DC=com'''' 
    WHERE objectGUID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(300), @ObjectGUID, 1) + '
    ORDER BY displayName;
 '')';

PRINT @Query; -- see what SQL is being executed
EXEC(@Query);
```

Comment: @user1633947 You have too many quotes when including the variable. The value itself does not get quoted. You have 4 single quotes which translates to 2 single quotes, but it is already in a string so that equates to an escaped-quote within a string. Meaning, you are not including the value of `@var` but instead are saying `WHERE objectGUID = '+@var+'` which is looking for a string literal of "+@var+". I have updated my answer with the corrected syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also storing objectGUID from AD into SQL server in my project and i use uniqueidentifier. (However I don't use OpenQuery but instead using a windows service to constantly sync from AD and populate the DB.)

Although when got from AD objectGUID appears as a binary array (varbinary),
it is actually representing a GUID, the corresponding type in SQL is uniqueidentifier.
And GUID is 16 byte in size (128 bits) only.

This is not tested, but please try something like this:

```
Select CONVERT(uniqueIdentifier,objectGUID) as Id, ...
FROM OpenQuery(ADSI,
    'SELECT objectGUID, ...
     FROM ...
     WHERE...')
```

Comment: Well, that sounds pathetically obvious now that you mention it ;-). It must have been too tired and not picked up on the "GUID" part of the name (yeah, I'm going with that). If this works I will +1.